# Block app from playing audio in the background (for productivity)

Tags: parental-control, productivity, focus, digital-wellbeing

I find myself easily wasting hours on social media and listening to podcasts. I now use apps that can be configured to block certain apps and certain websites at certain times of the day. These are called "digital well-being" apps or productivity apps. I'm currently using [Stay Focussed](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stayfocused). However, it doesn't stop me from using the player in Android's notifications area to play podcasts.

[image: Illustration]
*(Illustration from [here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/08/playing-nicely-with-media-controls.html))*

Is there a way to block certain audio apps from playing? Is there an app that does this? I want to block podcast apps completely at certain times of the day, even when I'm only accessing them from the audio notification panel.